# Calendly Not Appearing On Site (Site is Deployed with Netlify)

Tags: reactjs, netlify, calendly

Website Link: https://zen-stonebraker-8640d3.netlify.com/

I don't know what the issue is, Calendly isn't appearing on the site if you click on the site link and look. I'm not sure if it's an issue with my code or it's a deployment issue with Netlify. The widget is appearing on my localhost during production but doesn't show up during deployment. Please help.

```
import React from 'react';

class Calendly extends React.Component {
  calendlyScriptSrc = 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js';

  componentDidMount() {
    const head = document.querySelector('head');
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', this.calendlyScriptSrc);
    head.appendChild(script);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const head = document.querySelector('head');
    const script = document.querySelector('script');
    head.removeChild(script);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="schedule_form">
        <div
          className="calendly-inline-widget"
          data-url="https://calendly.com/handofgravity"
          style={{ minWidth: '480px', height: '640px' }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Calendly;
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

I put your code in a sandbox and it works there too: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shamir-u5rx0

I debugged the code on your website and it looks like Calendly's widget code successfully appends an iframe to `.calendly-inline-widget`, but shortly after that React re-renders your component, and when it does, it deletes all children from `.calendly-inline-widget` because it doesn't know about them.

I'm not exactly sure why React would have a reason to re-render the Calendly component, but here's what I would try:

- Change the Calendly component to be a `React.PureComponent` or better a functional component
- Have the component render a `div` with no attributes that contains the widget, like this

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="schedule_form">
        <div
          className="calendly-inline-widget"
          data-url="https://calendly.com/handofgravity"
          style={{ minWidth: '480px', height: '640px' }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or if you don't need `id="schedule_form"` on the `div` you already have, just strip that id attribute and avoid an extra nested div. This is just a guess based on the official documentation on [Integrating [React] with Other Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html). E.g. this is what they do in [Integrating with jQuery Chosen Plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-jquery-chosen-plugin):

> Notice how we wrapped `<select>` in an extra `<div>`. This is necessary because Chosen will append another DOM element right after the `<select>` node we passed to it. However, as far as React is concerned, `<div>` always only has a single child. This is how we ensure that React updates won’t conflict with the extra DOM node appended by Chosen. It is important that if you modify the DOM outside of React flow, you must ensure React doesn’t have a reason to touch those DOM nodes.

I believe we have a similar situation here. Maybe putting *any* kind of property on the wrapper div (even a hard-coded `id` property) messes things up.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. I resolved it by adding this :

```
{(typeof window != "undefined") && <script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>}
```

Hope it work for you too.

Jerome